# Schedule Batch Apex too many rows

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex, schedulebatch

I am having an issue because I believe I don't understand batch apex/scheduling very well. Every time I use this I get either a SOQL error of trying to query too many rows of 50001, or a DML error trying to add too many things in the list to update.
Any help would be greatly appreciated

The code

```
global class LastMktoSyncDate implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{


global List<sObject> start(Database.BatchableContext c)
{
    date d = system.today().addDays(-7);
    List<sObject> scope = new List<sObject>();

    scope.addAll([SELECT id, Name, Sync_to_mkto__c, account_name__c from Contact where ((Last_Marketo_Sync_Date__c = NULL OR Last_Marketo_Sync_Date__c < :d) AND Sync_To_Mkto__c != True)]);

    scope.addAll([SELECT id, Name, Sync_to_mkto__c from Lead where ((Last_Marketo_Sync_Date__c = NULL OR Last_Marketo_Sync_Date__c < :d) AND Sync_To_Mkto__c != True)]);

    return scope;
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext c, List<sObject> scope)
{
    List<Contact> con_toupdate = new List<Contact>();

    List<Lead> lead_toupdate = new List<Lead>(); 

    for(sObject obj : scope)
    {
        switch on obj
        {
            when Contact con
            {
                con.Last_Marketo_Sync_Date__c = system.today();
                con_toupdate.add(con);
            }
            when Lead lea
            {
                lea.Last_Marketo_Sync_Date__c = system.today();
                lead_toupdate.add(lea);
            }
         }
     }

    update con_toupdate;
    update lead_toupdate;
 }

 global void finish(Database.BatchableContext c)
 {
 }
}
```

The Scheduler

```
global class ScheduledMktoSync implements Schedulable{
    global void execute(SchedulableContext sc){
        LastMktoSyncDate l = new LastMktoSyncDate();
        database.executeBatch(l);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you do `addAll` you're still subject to the Apex Governor limits for a single transaction. That is, you're getting too many records and the list cannot iterate.

If you want to iterate on more records, you probably want to use a `QueryLocator` instead. Since you have two different queries, in your case that probably means that you're going to need two batch jobs (maybe you can chain them?)

An example of using a queryLocator follows:

```
public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    String query = 'SELECT Id FROM MyObject__c';

    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}
```

The rest of your code (`execute` and `finish`) remains unchanged other than making sure you're only processing records that match the querylocator you sent (contacts OR leads)

UPDATE:

A fun way of doing this with minimal repetition is to have a constructor in your class and then returning two different locators depending on a parameter.

For example:

```
String myQuery;

global LastMktoSyncDate(String objectName) {
    switch on objectName {
        when 'Contact' {
           myQuery = 'your query for contacts';
        }
        when 'Lead' {
           myQuery = 'your query for lead';
        }
    }
}

public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

    return Database.getQueryLocator(myQuery);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I was trying to be cheeky and not write a different class

Comment: Well, if you implement the suggestion you may not have to. :) Just call the same class with a different constructor on the `finish` method